# Need to know what the connection string in my web.config file should be set to for SQL server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hosting

I have created an asp.net website that connects to a SQL server database. Currently on my development machine I have the connection set to a SQL server express database with the file residing in the App_Data file of the website.

I now need to upload the site to my host of which I have an SQL server database set up. They have provided me with the name of the SQL server database - **mssql.mydomain.com** - but I'm not sure how to set up the connection string in the web.config file to point to this.

Any help would be much appreciated. - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
Server=mssql.mydomain.com;uid=user_id_goes_here;pwd=password_goes_here
```

Answer (score 1):

www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0):

Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=mssql.mydomain.com;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword

Does this work?